# Несгораема/Не сгораема

Tags: орфография

Поставил в ступор вопрос - как правильно пишется в контексте:
"...если эта сумма будет Несгораема/Не сгораема"
Как кажется, слитно?
На наречие (по задаваемому вопросу) не похоже, значит краткое прилагательное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эта сумма будет "несгораемой".

Если это условное свойство суммы (очков, денег) в рамках какой-либо игры, естественнее  приписать его в виде полного прилагательного и поместить в кавычки. Выражение же с кратким прилагательным (если эта сумма будет "несгораема") оставляет странное впечатление, будто не сумму сделали условно "несгораемой", а  она сама может активным образом проявить свойство "несгораемости": вдруг окажется, что сумма "несгораема".

Answer (score 3):

Несгораема. Краткое прилагательное. НЕ пишется слитно, так же, как в полном прилагательном НЕСГОРАЕМАЯ.

Несгораемый — прил. Такой, который не может сгореть; сделанный из огнеупорного материала. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000

Comment: А если так: "Он не сгораем  ни при каких условиях и почти вечен". Так правильно?

Answer (score 2):

"...если эта сумма будет несгораема" . Слитное написание НЕ с кратким прилагательным (именная часть сказуемого).

Раздельное написание подобных слов встречается редко: при усилении отрицания, при наличии зависимого слова в Т.п.. при этом оно должно употребляться без НЕ:
не узнаваема никем, не видим мною, но: никем непобедим (не употребляется без НЕ).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Вообще говоря, схема решения такова. Сначала определяем наличие двух форм написания - словарь подтверждает, что слово "сгораемый" существует. Исходный глагол "сгорать" - непереходный, следовательно это не причастие, а всегда только прилагательное. И единственный реальный вариант раздельного написания для прилагательного (кроме противопоставления) - это усилительный:"Он не сгораем ни при каких условиях и почти вечен".

Answer (score 1):

Если в прямом значении, то это причастие, а краткие причастия с "НЕ" пишутся раздельно. Если же в переносном смысле, то это отглагольное прилагательное, и оно пишется с "НЕ"слитно.